# Using Application Insights with Unit Tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, simple-injector, azure-application-insights

I have an MVC web app, and I'm using Simple Injector for DI.  Almost all my code is covered by unit tests.  However, now that I've added some telemetry calls in some controllers, I'm having trouble setting up the dependencies.

The telemetry calls are for sending metrics to the Microsoft Azure-hosted Application Insights service.  The app is not running in Azure, just a server with ISS. The AI portal tells you all kinds of things about your application, including any custom events you send using the telemetry library.  As a result, the controller requires an instance of Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient, which has no Interface and is a sealed class, with 2 constructors.  I tried registering it like so (the hybrid lifestyle is unrelated to this question, I just included it for completeness):

```
// hybrid lifestyle that gives precedence to web api request scope
var requestOrTransientLifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
    () => HttpContext.Current != null,
    new WebRequestLifestyle(),
    Lifestyle.Transient);

container.Register<TelemetryClient>(requestOrTransientLifestyle);
```

The problem is that since TelemetryClient has 2 constructors, SI complains and fails validation.  I found a post showing how to override the container's constructor resolution behavior, but that seems pretty complicated. First I wanted to back up and ask this question:

If I don't make the TelemetryClient an injected dependency (just create a New one in the class), will that telemetry get sent to Azure on every run of the unit test, creating lots of false data?  Or is Application Insights smart enough to know it is running in a unit test, and not send the data?

Any "Insights" into this issue would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I can't help with the AI side of the question but the registration can be done simply by registering a delegate that targets a specific constructor: `container.Register(() => new TelemetryClient(/*whatever constructor you want to target*/), requestOrTransientLifestyle);`. Also check out [DefaultScopedLifestyle](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#scoped)

Comment: For unit testing you should really define your own abstraction over TelemetryClient that you can mock as required. Unit tests should not be talking to Azure.

Comment: Your custom hybrid scope worries me. Mixing the web request lifestyle with a transient lifestyle is usually not a good practice. It can explain why you need this mixed lifestyle for?

Comment: @Steven - the hybrid scope was created as a way to deal with signalR needing to access the same service that the controller was using, but the service had been going out of scope.  That was done by another developer, and since my app is not using signalR, I have since removed it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient, which has no Interface and is a sealed class, with 2 constructors.

This `TelemetryClient` is a framework type and [framework types should not be auto-wired by your container](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97#Framework-types).

> I found a post showing how to override the container's constructor resolution behavior, but that seems pretty complicated.

Yep, this complexity is deliberate, because we want to discourage people from creating components with multiple constructors, because this is [an anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Instead of using auto-wiring, you can, as @qujck already pointed out, simply make the following registration:

```
container.Register<TelemetryClient>(() => 
    new TelemetryClient(/*whatever values you need*/),
    requestOrTransientLifestyle);
```

> Or is Application Insights smart enough to know it is running in a unit test, and not send the data?

Very unlikely. If you want to test the class that depends on this `TelemetryClient`, you better use a fake implementation instead, to prevent your unit test to either become fragile, slow, or to pollute your Insight data. But even if testing isn't a concern, according to the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) you should depend on (1) abstractions that are (2) defined by your own application. You fail both points when using the `TelemetryClient`.

What you should do instead is define one (or perhaps even multiple) abstractions over the `TelemetryClient` that are **especially tailored for your application**. So don't try to mimic the `TelemetryClient`'s API with its possible 100 methods, but only define methods on the interface that your controller actually uses, and make them as *simple as possible* so you can make both the controller's code simpler -and- your unit tests simpler.

After you defined a good abstraction, you can create an adapter implementation that uses the `TelemetryClient` internally. I image you register this adapter as follows:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<ITelemetryLogger>(
    new TelemetryClientAdapter(new TelemetryClient(...)));
```

Here I assume that the `TelemetryClient` is thread-safe and can work as a singleton. Otherwise, you can do something like this:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<ITelemetryLogger>(
    new TelemetryClientAdapter(() => new TelemetryClient(...)));
```

Here the adapter is still a singleton, but is provided with a delegate that allows creation of the `TelemetryClient`. Another option is to let the adapter create (and perhaps dispose) the `TelemetryClient` internally. That would perhaps make the registration even simpler:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<ITelemetryLogger>(new TelemetryClientAdapter());
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer.  As Steve and @qujck suggested, my main question was answered with a simple one-liner to register the telemetryclient with the constructor of my choice (although Steve's answer has a typo - container.Register is duplicated).  After posting this question I arrived at pretty much the same solution to the unit testing issue - wrapping TelemetryClient in a simple class of my own design, exposing the one method I need, created an interface for it, etc.  Then in the unit testing, that simple wrapper class is Mocked with Moq.

Answer (score 47):

Application Insights has an [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/37cec526194b833f7cd676f25eafd985dd88d3fa/Test/CoreSDK.Test/Operation.AL.Shared.Tests/TelemetryClientExtensionAsyncTests.cs#L28-L32) of unit testing the `TelemetryClient` by mocking `TelemetryChannel`.

`TelemetryChannel` implements `ITelemetryChannel` so is pretty easy to mock and inject. In this example you can log messages, and then collect them later from `Items` for assertions.

```
public class MockTelemetryChannel : ITelemetryChannel
{
    public IList<ITelemetry> Items
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    ...

    public void Send(ITelemetry item)
    {
        Items.Add(item);
    }
}

...

MockTelemetryChannel = new MockTelemetryChannel();

TelemetryConfiguration configuration = new TelemetryConfiguration
{
    TelemetryChannel = MockTelemetryChannel,
    InstrumentationKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
};
configuration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer());

TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);

container.Register<TelemetryClient>(telemetryClient);
```

Comment: And what would you use for the run time code? I tried to use `ServerTelemetryChannel`, but received a trace telemetry that "Server telemetry channel was not initialized. So persistent storage is turned off. You need to call ServerTelemetryChannel.Initialize()." But the intellisense on `Initialize()` says it's for internal use.

Comment: Correction: But `Initialize()` Accepts a `TelemetryConfiguration`, which is what we're trying to create here.

Comment: @TsahiAsher, I would suggest posting a new question for that one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33820340/141022 has a persuasive argument for creating a sound abstraction around a 3rd party dependency, it's worth noting the AppInsights team (albeit an old post) do also recommend using the channel route  https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/342 (at least at the moment, they might be considering new approaches).

Answer (score 38):

I had a lot of success with using Josh Rostad's [article](https://medium.com/@jrolstad/unit-testing-and-microsoft-application-insights-6db0929b39e6) for writing my mock TelemetryChannel and injecting it into my tests. Here's the mock object:

```
public class MockTelemetryChannel : ITelemetryChannel
{
    public ConcurrentBag<ITelemetry> SentTelemtries = new ConcurrentBag<ITelemetry>();
    public bool IsFlushed { get; private set; }
    public bool? DeveloperMode { get; set; }
    public string EndpointAddress { get; set; }

    public void Send(ITelemetry item)
    {
        this.SentTelemtries.Add(item);
    }

    public void Flush()
    {
        this.IsFlushed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

And then in my tests, a local method to spin-up the mock:

```
private TelemetryClient InitializeMockTelemetryChannel()
{
    // Application Insights TelemetryClient doesn't have an interface (and is sealed)
    // Spin -up our own homebrew mock object
    MockTelemetryChannel mockTelemetryChannel = new MockTelemetryChannel();
    TelemetryConfiguration mockTelemetryConfig = new TelemetryConfiguration
    {
        TelemetryChannel = mockTelemetryChannel,
        InstrumentationKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    };

    TelemetryClient mockTelemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(mockTelemetryConfig);
    return mockTelemetryClient;
}
```

Finally, run the tests!

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestWidgetDoSomething()
{            
    //arrange
    TelemetryClient mockTelemetryClient = this.InitializeMockTelemetryChannel();
    MyWidget widget = new MyWidget(mockTelemetryClient);

    //act
    var result = widget.DoSomething();

    //assert
    Assert.IsTrue(result != null);
    Assert.IsTrue(result.IsSuccess);
}
```

Comment: thank you for this very clean and easy to implement solution! thanks in addition for your non-smarty and friendly wording of your answer. Every other answer has some "container" code which I don't understand: My unit tests never have any "containers" to register types. this answer should be the accepted unswer.

Comment: Exactly. I agree that this answer is more straightforward. I also had success using a very similar approach.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to go down the abstraction / wrapper path. In your tests you could simply direct the AppInsights endpoint to a mock lightweight http server (which is trivial in ASP.NET Core).

appInsightsSettings.json

```
    "ApplicationInsights": {
    "Endpoint": "http://localhost:8888/v2/track"
}
```

How to set up "TestServer" in ASP.NET Core http://josephwoodward.co.uk/2016/07/integration-testing-asp-net-core-middleware

Answer (score 4):

Another option without going the abstraction route is to disable telemetry before doing running your tests:

`TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;`

Comment: This requires using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility, but we should note that TelemetryConfiguration.Active is obsolete in .Net Core.

Answer (score 4):

Based on other work here;

1. Create the channel - you can use this for testing telemetries if needed

```
    public class MockTelemetryChannel : ITelemetryChannel
    {
        public ConcurrentBag<ITelemetry> SentTelemtries = new();
        public bool IsFlushed { get; private set; }
        public bool? DeveloperMode { get; set; }
        public string EndpointAddress { get; set; }

        public void Send(ITelemetry item)
        {
            this.SentTelemtries.Add(item);
        }

        public void Flush()
        {
            this.IsFlushed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
```

2. Use a nice little static factory class

```
    public static class MockTelemetryClient
    {
        public static TelemetryClient Create()
        {
            var mockTelemetryChannel = new MockTelemetryChannel();
            var mockTelemetryConfig = new TelemetryConfiguration
            {
                TelemetryChannel = mockTelemetryChannel,
                InstrumentationKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            };

            var mockTelemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(mockTelemetryConfig);
            return mockTelemetryClient;
        }
    }
```

3. Call `MockTelemetryClient.Create()` to get your `TelemetryClient`
4. Profit

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine wrote this useful library that introduces abstractions for some of these core telemetry types (e.g. `ITelemetryClient` and `IMetric`).

https://github.com/thomhurst/ApplicationInsights.TelemetryLogger

Very easy to implement. You'll barely have to change anything in your production code, and mocking in tests becomes a breeze. Here's an extract from the README:

#### Dependency Injection

Call `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()` as normal, and then call `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryClientInterfaces()`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()
        .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryClientInterfaces();
}
```

#### ITelemetryClient

Want the same usage as `TelemetryClient`? Inject `ITelemetryClient` into your classes. It has all the available methods of `TelemetryClient` (apart from any methods which shouldn't be called. e.g. internal or deprecated).

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ITelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

    public MyClass(ITelemetryClient telemetryClient)
    {
        _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    }
    
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _telemetryClient.TrackTrace("Something happened");
    }
}
```

Comment: its not the right answer, but i found it the most useful!